# Creating MySQLi table with ID auto_increment return syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating MYSQLi table with PHP code but it returns syntax error.

```
<?php
    require_once('../connect.php');

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $query = "CREATE TABLE email_list (
            id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
            first_name varchar(20),
            last_name varchar(20),
            email varchar(60),
            PRIMARY_KEY (id) );";

    if (mysqli_query ($dbc, $query)) {
          echo "The query was successfully executed!<br />";
        } else {
              echo "The query could not be executed!" .  mysqli_error($dbc);
        } 

        mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Error:

> The query could not be executed!You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '(`id`) )' at line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is

```
PRIMARY KEY
```

Instead of

```
PRIMARY_KEY
```

Comment: opps. Thanks. I am going to mark it solved once time allowed.